# MaxItemCount in Azure Functions/Cosmos DB

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

For Python API for Azure Functions serverless and Comsmos DB input binding. Is it possible to tune maxitemcount? Or is it dynamically set. I do some queries resulting in large results and it seems the bottleneck is throughput between Cosmos DB and the executing HTTP-triggered function.

/MG

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [SQL Query input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=python#queue-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-sqlquery-2) option, you should be able to use the [`LIMIT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-offset-limit) along with `ORDER BY` to set a maximum number of records returned. You may also want to take a look at the metrics on your Cosmos account, just in case the maxing out your available RUs causing the bottleneck.

Comment: Sure, but the python SDK for cosmos also has a "maxitemscount" parameter, which speeds up large extraction. How is this implemented i azure functions?

Comment: It isn't currently implemented in the input binding. The full list of what is available is in the binding documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=python It won't help right this minute, but you may wish to raise an issue on the Python worker repo to request that this be added. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker

Comment: Would you happen to know what the default value of maxitemscount is when using input binding in Functions?

Comment: @AnupamChand The Cosmos API has a default max item count of 100. I don't see anything in the Webjobs SDK that overrides this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#pagination-of-query-results